# Step error in sqlite3_create_function_v2

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm using the sqlite3_create_function_v2 to define a ngram function.

In this case the step is used as the xFunc pointer, it works as a charm, the signature for the step and the xFunc is the same.

```
sqlite3_create_function_v2(this->connection, "ngram", 3, SQLITE_ANY, NULL, SqliteExtension::stepExtendNGram, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

When i try to use the step as the step it compiles but when i execute the command with the ngram it fails in the prepare statement.

```
sqlite3_create_function_v2(this->connection, "ngram", 3, SQLITE_ANY, NULL, NULL, SqliteExtension::stepExtendNGram, SqliteExtension::finalExtendNGram, NULL);
```

The SqliteExtension Code, for test the NGRAM is not yet implemented

```
void SqliteExtension::stepExtendNGram(sqlite3_context *ctx, int nArg, sqlite3_value ** val){
    //3 PARAMS
    std::cout << "P1 " << sqlite3_value_text(val[0]) << " P2 " << sqlite3_value_text(val[1]) << std::endl;
    sqlite3_result_int(ctx, atoi((const char*) sqlite3_value_text(val[0])));

}

void SqliteExtension::finalExtendNGram(sqlite3_context *ctx){
}
```

Sql call `select * from tbl_lista where ngram(id, "Asd", 3) > 1`

The first parameter is the column, the second is the text to compare each column, the third is the N param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" my problem.
It is not a problem, only the step/finaize is for agregate functions where i need to run trough all the lines to return one data on the finalize.
The ngram is for each line, so this approach dont works.